# What's the proper way to cast wstring to wchar*? (or string to char*)

Tags: d

[I'm new to D (currently writing my first useful program) and I don't have much C background - just some C# and other mostly pointerless languages.]

Do I need to always append '\0' to the wstring before casting?  Is that the only way to ensure that my wchar* will be null-terminated?  When it is cast, is it a new copy of the wstring, or does it just get a pointer to the same wstring you're casting?

Comment: Wow, the imports can start to add up when you want to do basic string operations.  I've got std.utf, std.string, std.c.string, and std.c.wcharh.  <-- Nevermind - it looks like I just need std.string and std.utf.

Answer (score 9):

The `toStringz` functions convert D strings to C-style zero-terminated strings.

```
immutable(char)* toStringz(const(char)[] s); 
immutable(char)* toStringz(string s);
```

e.g.

```
string s;
immutable(char)* cstr = s.toStringz();
//or: toStringz(s);
```

`toStringz` allocates a new string on the heap only if the string isn't already null terminated, otherwise it just returns `s.ptr`.

Comment: toStringZ - I guess that explains why there isn't a toUTF8z function.

Answer (score 9):

For calling Windows *W functions use http://www.digitalmars.com/d/2.0/phobos/std_utf.html#toUTF16z

Also note that string *literals* already are 0-terminated so you can pass them directly.

Comment: toUTF16**z** - missed that one, thanks!  Didn't know that about literals either - thanks.

Answer (score 8):

If you merely want a pointer, the correct way is to use the 'ptr' property (available for all dynamic arrays, not just strings)

```
str.ptr
```

However, if you are wanting something to use with C, to ensure it is nul-terminated, use `toStringz`

```
import std.string;
toStringz(str);
```

`toStringz` will not perform a copy if the string is already nul terminated.